# What kids film had two flying spheres, one red, one yellow?

Tags: movie, story-identification

I am trying to remember a film, from the '80s maybe. I think it was a children's movie.

In the film there were flying spheres. It may have had a sequel with the wedding the two of the spheres: one of them was red and other one was yellow. (I may be misremembering the wedding part.)

These spheres look like flying Pokemon balls. They may have had knives. I remember a scene with a guy and a little child and an ally flying red sphere.

I can't remember country of origin, but it was a colored film that I watched in my native language. It must be an American or European film so it should be English.
Is any one looking for the same film.It was flubber it's look like https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/kVw4TdMbXdSBZzjNYThhKfWwSKO.jpg
And it is including a professor a one flying yellow sphere,red sphere,a wedding,child film.

Comment: It is always helpful to include information such as what original language the film was in, country (if applicable), etc...

Comment: I remember a film from1979 with flying spheres that had knives coming out of them... Not a kid's movie though. Oh, and the sequel had silver and golden spheres.

Comment: *Phantasm* is what you're thinking of, Mr. Lister.

Comment: Phantasm  i don't think so.But i will give a shot.But i remember it more colorfu and i also remember a scene that a man a child and a flying sphere were inside at a garrage or something.

Comment: When you say "colored film", do you mean that it was projected in color, or that it's animated?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like either Phantasm or Phantasm 3.

Comment: Not animated.It was looking an old child film maybe from 80-90's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I'm just going to take a shot at this, but two movies come to mind, and I'm not sure if they are what you are looking for, but here goes nothing:

Batteries not Included:1987- this is a kids movie, PG at least and it is from the right decade, but the robots are not spheres, they are more like saucers, but thought that might be it.

or could it be,

Flubber: 1997- Remake of the classic older movie, geared for children, but with the floating yellow orb that you mention, and a lot of the movie takes place in his basement laboratory. There's a scene where the orb fights off some criminals, not sure if it involves knives though. Also, I'm pretty sure he gets married to the orb at the end. I feel like this one, despite having more of the criteria you are searching for may be a long shot because its a newer movie and has Robin Williams in it, so I figured you'd probably recall that.

Comment: @ Alpertunga Yuce : Was it not Flubber?, your comment went away. I was thinking I just solved a mystery. :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much and thank you again Flubber was true. :))).All guys thanks for help in my search.Finally i can sleep well.

Comment: Wait, Robin Williams gets married to an orb in Flubber?